What is the meaning of the end of "The Beast Within"?
At the end of The Beast Within, we see a rapid succession of scenes from the film, which show Noah behaving in a monstrous way when he is not transformed into a werewolf.
Is the implication that he is just a regular abusive spouse, with his appearance as a werewolf being metaphorical? But then, is the scene at the beginning where the werewolf—presumably his grandfather—eats someone's face off metaphorical as well? Is the idea instead that he simply believes that he turns into a werewolf at the full moon? (But then, isn't chaining him up and giving him livestock to kill going a bit far)? Or is there something else going on?

"With renewed clarity, flashbacks show Willow that Noah was merely an abusive husband/father all along, and her imagination manifested his mood swings as him becoming a wolf."
